problem using python_yolov8 with .net enviroment
I'm trying to use YOLO pose detection from C# with the .NET framework, using the pythonnet NuGet package. However, I'm encountering a problem due to Python's Global Interpreter Lock (GIL), which allows only one thread at a time, while YOLO uses multiple threads. This is causing issues. Are there any workarounds or solutions for this problem? Any advice would be appreciated.
I try to use multiprocessing but it didnt work. it turn into loop.

Hi, please provide the minimal reproducible example. Overall it is not clear why are you calling python script from C#. Also it is not clear what the issue with the threads, because YOLO inference must be done on the GPU where GIL is irrelevant. The question would benefit if you'll add some code and more information about your software/hardware setup
